# Are there newer manuals / documentation / help files for script#?

Tags: script#

While searching the internet for a while, looking for some kind of comprehensive reference material for Script#, I've only been able to find a manual from 2007:  http://code.google.com/p/extsharp/downloads/detail?name=ScriptSharp-v0.4.2.pdf&can=2&q=

Is anything newer available?

I see on the website, http://scriptsharp.com/, it says "Stay tuned... updated site with more information and documentation coming soon!"

Unfortunately, there's nothing to say when the message was written, so I don't know how long it's been up there, or when "soon" might be.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm working on it... challenge has been I am also working on some big changes to improve it as well.

I totally realize the need for docs though. Is there a specific question I can help with in the meantime if you're blocked on something?

Comment: Thanks Nikhil.  I think I'll wait to accept an answer on this when the documentation is ready.  I wrote this question while looking to see what attributes are available for adjusting imported property names from JS.  I wondered if there was an attribute that would convert, for example, "FooBar" (in C#) to "_fooBar" (in JS).